# Using fork and execvp in c causing error

Tags: c, execvp

I am attempting to use fork/execvp to execute another program from within my C program. It is working, however before ls outputs the contents of my directory I am getting several hundred lines of:

```
ls: cannot access : No such file or directory
```

Followed by the correct listing of the files in the directory. I am passing to execvp:

```
char **argv = {"ls", "/home/school/"};
char *command = "ls";
```

For some reason when I use the path "/home/school" it cannot find the directory. Does anyone know why that is happening and why ls is saying it cannot access?

```
PID  = fork();
i = 0;
if(i == numArgs) { doneFlag = 1; }
    if (PID == 0){//child process
        execvp(command, argv);//needs error checking
    }
    else if(PID > 0){
        wait(PID, 0, 0);//wait for child process to finish execution
    }
    else if(PID == -1){
        printf("ERROR:\n");
        switch (errno){
            case EAGAIN:
         printf("Cannot fork process: System Process Limit Reached\n");
         case ENOMEM:
         printf("Cannot fork process: Out of memory\n");
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: maybe try `char **argv = {"ls", "/home/school/", (void*)0};` ?

Comment: does (void*)0 need to be in quotes? I am getting warnings when I use (void*)0

Comment: OT: you should add `break` statements in your error `case`s

Comment: @user1768079 `(char *)0`  is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***execv*** and ***execvp*** functions provide an array of pointers to **null-terminated strings** that represent the argument list available to the new program.

The first argument should point to the file name associated with the file being executed.

The array of pointers *must* be terminated by a **NULL** pointer. Append a `0` or `NULL` at the end of `argv*`.

Comment: the last element of `argv` must be `NULL` or `(char *)0` but not `'\0'`

Comment: Thank you, This answer + comment answered the question for me. It is working as expected now.

Comment: Thank you @IngoLeonhardt for pointing that out. I happen to mess up pointers and strings quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

The `char**` argument passed in `execvp()` must be terminated by `NULL`.

Comment: Do you mean the strings stored by char** or the char** itself, like the last row must be a null pointer?

Comment: @user1768079 last element in the list of `char*`s must be `NULL`. Hope this helps!